# How do I keep text from rotating when rotating an op amp in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz, rotating, text, text-manipulation

As you can see when running the MWE, the minus sign of the op amp is vertical. What is the easiest way to make it horizontal?

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 0) node[op amp, rotate=90] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a custom symbol:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 0) node[op amp, rotate=90,
    amp minus = \rotatebox{90}{$-$}] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See the manual around page 143, "Input and output pins symbols".

Notice, however that this works only with fonts where the math minus and math plus have the same box (which I think is just Computer Modern or derivates):

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 0) node[op amp, rotate=90,
    amp minus = \rotatebox{90}{$-$}] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, you need to use the same trick applied [since version 1.6.3](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/721):

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 0) node[op amp, rotate=90,
    amp minus = \rotatebox{90}{$\vphantom{+}-$}] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it's better to encase the option in a style:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\tikzset{up op amp/.style={op amp, rotate=90,
            amp minus = \rotatebox{90}{$\vphantom{+}-$}}
        }
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 0) node[up op amp] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

(same output as before)